# node express server request.on('end') only firing for get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a middleware function that fires when the request has ended.

middleware

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    req.on("end", function() {
        console.log('End');
    });
    next();
};
```

I include my middleware like this.

```
app.all('/*', [require('./middlewares/activityLogger.js')]);
```

at the moment i see "END in console for GET request but not for POST, PUT and DELETE"

example of how i end request
GET (WORKS)

```
res.status(200).json(result)
```

POST (Don't work)

```
res.status(201).json(result.create)
```

any suggesting to why my middleware function is only fired on GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by listening to the "finish" event instead of "end"

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('finish');
    });
    next();
};
```